# OpenGL reverse movement

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm trying to decrease the values of 'left_eye_b' and 'left_eye_b'and then increase the values again to simulate wink on a human I made on OpenGL.

Here I created the eye:

```
left_eye_b=10.0;
left_eye_s=10.0;
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (float i = 0; i <= (2 * p); i += 0.001) {           // Left Eye Inside
        x = 10.0 * cos(i) - 24.56;
        y = left_eye_s * sin(i) + 56.45;
        glVertex2f(x, y);
    }
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glPointSize(2);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (float i = 0; i <= (2 * p); i += 0.001) {           // Left Eye Border
        x = 10.0 * cos(i) - 24.56;
        y = left_eye_b * sin(i) + 56.45;
        glVertex2f(x, y);
    }
    glEnd();
```

Here is where I tried to make the eye wink:

```
void timer(int a) {
    /// Simulating Wink
    if (left_eye_b >= 1.12)
        left_eye_b -= 0.1;          // Eye Close
    if (left_eye_s >= 1.12)
        left_eye_s -= 0.1;
    glutTimerFunc(10, timer, 1);
    if (left_eye_b <= 10.0)
        left_eye_b += 0.1;          // Eye Open
    if (left_eye_s <= 10.0)
        left_eye_s += 0.1;

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(10, timer, 1);

}
```

Problem statement:
If I remove the 'eye open' part, I works perfectly and the eye closes.
However, I want to use the 'Eye Open' part to make increase the values back and
open the eye again after a few seconds.

Any suggestion about how that can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable that indicates whether the eye will be opened or closed. The value of the variable is 1.0 to open and -1.0 to close:

```cpp
double eye_change = -1.0;
```

Change the sign of the variable when the exe has opened or closed:

```cpp
void timer(int a) {

    left_eye_b += 0.1 * eye_change; 
    left_eye_s += 0.1 * eye_change; 

    if (left_eye_b <= 1.12)
        eye_change = 1.0;
    if (left_eye_b >= 10.0)
        eye_change = -1.0;

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(10, timer, 1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this code. It's not working, as I can see the eye is not opening or closing at all.

Comment: Yes it is global

Comment: Viva @Rabbid76. It works now. Thanks. Do you know how to set a specific timer between close and open?